# Trouble outputing file size to a label from a listbox in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I'm using `os.path.getsize()` to output the size of a file to a label. The file path is stored in a listbox. The function works, but it outputs the file size in bits, so I wrote the following to convert to more appropriate units, and it is now displaying only in TB. It's executing all of the `if` statements, regardless if the condition is true.

```
activeFile = FilesList.get(ACTIVE)
fileSize = os.path.getsize(activeFile)
fileSizeStr = str(fileSize) + ' Bits'

if fileSize > 8:
    fileSize = fileSize / 8
    fileSizeStr = str(fileSize) + ' Bytes'

if fileSize < 1024:
    fileSize = fileSize / 1024
    fileSizeStr = str(fileSize) + ' KB'

if fileSize < 1024:
    fileSize = fileSize / 1024
    fileSizeStr = str(fileSize) + ' MB'

if fileSize < 1024:
    fileSize = fileSize / 1024
    fileSizeStr = str (fileSize) + ' GB'

if fileSize < 1024:
    fileSize = fileSize / 1024
    fileSizeStr = str(fileSize) + ' TB'
```

Comment: Should it be `if fileSize >= 1024:` ?

Comment: You are setting the value of fileSize in each if clause. If the first < 1024 is true then division will make fileSize smaller each time which will always be true, unless i am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems in your code,

- You always re-assign `fileSizeStr`. You need to concatenate new values.
- You need to check if `fileSize` greater than or equal to 1024, not smaller.
- New `fileSize` should be remainder of the first calculation, not the result of it.

Also, checking from larger one would be better IMHO.

```
#constants
TB = 2**43
GB = 2**33
MB = 2**23
KB = 2**13
BYTES = 2**3

#some test value here
fileSize = 8

#empty string to be filled and shown later
fileSizeStr = ""

#calculations
if fileSize >= TB:
    fileTB = fileSize / TB
    fileSize = fileSize % TB
    fileSizeStr += str(fileTB) + 'TB '

if fileSize >= GB:
    fileGB = fileSize / GB
    fileSize = fileSize % GB
    fileSizeStr += str(fileGB) + 'GB '

if fileSize >= MB:
    fileMB = fileSize / MB
    fileSize = fileSize % MB
    fileSizeStr += str(fileMB) + 'MB '

if fileSize >= KB:
    fileKB = fileSize / KB
    fileSize = fileSize % KB
    fileSizeStr += str(fileKB) + 'KB '

if fileSize >= BYTES:
    fileB = fileSize / BYTES
    fileSize = fileSize % BYTES
    fileSizeStr += str(fileB) + 'Byte(s) '

fileSizeStr += str(fileSize) + 'Bit(s)'

print fileSizeStr
```

Comment: @CurlyJoe Ofcourse it is good idea in other cases but in this case, I want it to check to other ones aswell. Not just check one and break.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea what a help this is!